# How to ask Github Desktop to launch x64 powershell when click "Open in Git Shell"

Tags: powershell, github-desktop

In the options, I choose `Custom` shell and point to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`. But it still launches 32-bit powershell for me. What should I do for now?

Comment: Are you sure you're running a 64-bit system? According to [at least one article](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/PowerShell_Executables_File_System_Locations) and my personal testing on Windows 7 64-bit that would appear to be the correct path. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055924/how-to-launch-64-bit-powershell-from-32-bit-cmd-exe) and [this](http://www.gregorystrike.com/2011/01/27/how-to-tell-if-powershell-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/) for further information.

Comment: @Seth, yes, I'm pretty sure that I'm in a 64-bit system. I use `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` command to determine if a powershell session is 64 or 32 bit. Only Github Desktop makes it wrong.

Comment: Is the GitHub Desktop executable a 32-bit or 64-bit one? Maybe, if it is a 32-bit one, the mapping changes dynamically?

Comment: Use `C:\Windows\Sysnative` instead of `C:\Windows\System32` to bypass [file system redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx) as @Seth already linked to [How to launch 64-bit powershell from 32-bit cmd.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19056011/3439404).

Comment: @Seth merits reward…

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, I did edit my old (wrong) answer. I wouldn't mind if you got the rep though. So feel free to write an answer as well and let the author of the question decide. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Desktop seems to be a 32-bit application. As you're running it on a 64-bit system Windows changes certain paths and environment variables in the background using [file system redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx). This also happens e.g. for the registry. Both is done in order for the 32-bit application to find the files it needs in the appropriate places.

So while a 64-bit application launching `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` would start a 64-bit PowerShell a 32-bit application would launch a 32-bit PowerShell. If you go ahead an check the question ["How to launch 64-bit powershell from 32-bit cmd.exe?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055924/how-to-launch-64-bit-powershell-from-32-bit-cmd-exe) you will find that you should be able to use a path that references `sysnative` instead of `system32` in order to launch a 64-bit application from a 32-bit application. So you would reference:

`%SystemRoot%\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

This isn't working for me on Windows 7 64-bit though it should be available for systems since Vista.

[This article](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) seems to have a bit more information about the whole thing and [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130321-00/?p=4883/) as some more in depth information about side effects if you opt to disable the redirection.